# How can I record JMeter scripts behind company's proxy auto config (PAC) file?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

- The Internet Options settings are managed by my company's system administrator.
- The Proxy is set to use automatic configuration script (http://proxypac.abcd.com/proxyrouting). I cannot disable this.
- I cannot change the proxy to localhost. The above PAC script will override no matter what I try to change.
- The IT security does not allow me to install Chrome Blazemeter plugin, or install Badboy, or use Fiddler, or be able to manually change the proxy.
- The company's proxy host is proxy.abcd.com and port is 8080, but I don't know how this info will help if the browser is reading the PAC file.

Is there any option for me to record JMeter scripts in the above scenario?

Is there any way for me to create GUI scripts with plenty of data and dynamic values coming back from the server without recording (if recording is not an option in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a browser which doesn't use operating system proxy settings, a good example is [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). You need to configure Firefox to use JMeter as the proxy

   [image]
2. Once done you can [configure JMeter to use your company proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) by putting the following lines to [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/):

   ```
   http.proxyHost=proxy.abcd.com
   https.proxyHost=proxy.abcd.com
   http.proxyPort=8080
   https.proxyPort=8080
   ```

These [PAC files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file) don't do any magic, they're normal [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) files which are being interpreted by browsers to determine which proxy should be used for which URL. For certain URLs you might not even need to use the proxy. So I would recommend checking whether you really need the proxy for accessing the application you're trying to record, it might be the case you don't need this step #2

Comment: Thanks Dmitri - I forgot to mention, but we don't have Mozilla Firefox. IT security does not allow any other browsers than IE and Chrome. So that's not an option for me.

Comment: You can save [all the network requests to a HAR file](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#save-as-har) from Chrome and then either use [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) or standalone [Har2jmeter](https://seitenbau.github.io/har2JMeter/) or create relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers manually